# textview at the bottom of my layout not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok so I have a layout which looks something like this:

```
LinearLayout
  TextView
  LinearLayout (Horizontal)
    TextView
    CustomImageView
  \LinearLayout
  TextView
\LinearLayout
```

But my bottom textview is being cut off and is not displaying. My inner LinearLayout and custom view both have wrap_content parameters for their layout height. What can I do to ensure that the bottom TextView will display?

EDIT(s):

This the xml for the bottom textview:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="title"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

Also a scrollview is not useful for my project, the textviews need to be displayed on the same screen.

Comment: show some brief of xml what r attribute of TextView

Comment: try putting scrollview as layout root.  See if you can view your TextView..

Comment: Can you post the screen shot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the best way** is to use a `RelativeLayout` at the Top Level instead of a `LinearLayout` , and then you can place your textView at the bottom by using : `android:alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: This does display the textview at the bottom, but it overlaps with the imageview above it. If I add android:layout_below to the TextView, then I get the same problem and it gets cut off the screen again.

Comment: if you are defining your ImageView as fill_parent , it will overlap with the textView, add your layout Xml and i will fix it to you :)

Comment: Just fixed it. Had to place the bottom textview above the imageview and set the imageview to be above it with android:layout_above. Thanks for you help though!

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to have top level RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, it will do.

Another one is make use of ScrollView at top level of your current layout.

Hope it helps!